# How to make proxy

Tags: java, sockets

I have a server which sends rest requests to local machine and this local machine should execute request and send back to server. I read that the best way to do that is using 2 sockets. Where first socket establish connection between server and local client and second read from first and executes.

I am stuck on the second one as it requires an address prior to opening like

```
Socket s = new Socket(InetAddress.getByName("stackoverflow.com"), 80);

PrintWriter pw = new PrintWriter(s.getOutputStream());
pw.println("GET / HTTP/1.1");
pw.println("Host: stackoverflow.com");
pw.flush();

BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(s.getInputStream()));

String t;
while((t = br.readLine()) != null)
    System.out.println(t);

br.close();
```

So i dont understand how to make second one to execute request

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use two separate threads for both connections  .you have to have client and server both in local machine and server (asw or other).client in local machine will communicate with server in server (aws or other) .and the client in the server will communicate with the server in local machine .you can find the ip of the local machine form server (asw) from the packets which are sent by the client in local machine .if you are using a private network then task will be some one difficult to achieve .

Comment: I undestend about thread and other, i dont understend what to wtite inside Socket s = new Socket() of executor